# How does the while loop work when the assignment and postfix operators are used in its condition

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, c-strings, postfix-operator

I found this code in a book on pointers and the book explains for the following code that. First the value at the address stored in `ss` replaces the value at the address stored it `tt`. After the assignment, the test is carried out to decide whether the `while` loop should continue or not. Since `*tt` gives `'l'` which is the true value.
Next both `ss` and `tt` are incremented.

My questions are:

1. Why does the while loop first assigns the value and then check for true or false?
2. Why is the value at `tt` checked, I mean why particularly `tt`?
3. Why are `ss` and `tt` incremented after checking the condition; why not just after assigning the value?

```
int main()
{ 
    char s[]="lumps, bumps, swollen veins, new pains";
    char t[40];
    char *ss,*tt;
    tt=t;
    ss=s;
    while (*tt++ = *ss++ );
    printf("%s ",t);
}
```

output:

```
lumps, bumps, swollen veins, new pains
```

Comment: C and C++ are not same. Choose a single tag.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the question was tagged as c++ first. In c I agree, while in c++ I never encountered this pattern

Answer (score 1):

> 1. why does the while loop first assigns the value and then check for true or false 2.

It copies the `char`, and then it checks if the copied char was the null terminator. If it is, then it evaluates to `0` (or `false`) and the loop stops.

> why value at tt is checked, i mean why particularly tt.

Actually it's the result of the `=` that is checked, which is equal to the value that was assigned. So if `*ss` is `'\0'`, then the `=` returns `'\0'` and the loop stops, because `'\0'` is equal to `0` or `false`.

> why ss and tt are increment after checking the condition why not just
>   after assigning the value

This is postifix increment, so the assignment (`=`) is done with the old values, not the incremented values.

Answer (score 0):

An expression like this

```
*ss++
```

can be equivalently rewritten like

```
*( ss++ )
```

That is the postfix increment operator `++` has a higher priority than the unary operator `*`.

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators, p. #2)

> 2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
>   As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it). ... The value
>   computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of
>   updating the stored value of the operand....

So if for example the pointer `ss` points to the first character of the string `s` then the value of the expression `ss++` is this address and only after returning the address the pointer is incremented.

Then the returned pointer that is the value of the expression `ss++` is dereferenced and the value of the expression `*( ss++ )` is the first character of the string stored in the array `s`.

Similarly the value of the expression `*( tt++ )` is the object pointed to by the pointer `tt` before its incrementing.

So the first character of the array `t` is assigned with the first character of the array `s`.

Further according to the C Standard (6.5.16 Assignment operators, p. #3)

> 3 An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by
>   the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left
>   operand after the assignment,111) but is not an lvalue....

So in the first step of the loop the value of the assignment operator is the character `'l'`.

And at last (6.8.5 Iteration statements, p. #4)

> 4 An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to be
>   executed repeatedly until the controlling expression compares equal to
>   0...

As the result of the assignment expression (the character `'l'`) is not equal to 0 then the loop continues. It will be executed until the expression `*( ss++ )` returns the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the array `s` that is assigned to the array `t` using the assignment expression `*tt++ = *ss++`.

As in this case the result of the assignment expression is the character `'\0'` (that is promoted to `0` of the type `int`) then the loop stops its iterations.

As result the array `t` contains the string stored in the array `s`.